# performance wise, what is better: AsyncTask or simply create a runnable?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I am currently working on an Android project which loads a lot of pictures onCreate. To make sure the UI doesn't get blocked I have the option to put it in a runnable or an AsyncTask. What is (performance wise) the better option or is it practically the same?

Comment: If you create threads (or Runnables) make sure you use ThreadPools as not controlling thread creation is not a good practice. AsyncTask gives more flexibility and you can separate out the AsynTask into a separate class (generic or specific). If it is just one activity go for AsyncTask else Threads suits nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's more or less the same.`AsyncTask` is nothing else than an convenience-class for `Runnable/Thread`.

In my opinion you should use `AsyncTask`. It's kind of an android standard plus it takes the task away from you to check when the work is finished. You can easily make a callback in the `onPostExecute` or do whatever you want with the result. (Remeber that only `doInBackGround` runs in an own thread - the other methods run in the UI thread, so you can even add dialogs there and so on if you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you attach your `Runnable` on a new `Thread` then practically both would do the same under the hood. However, it is more easier to follow `AsyncTask` life-cycle and its the recommended way of doing parallel things in android. Therefore, my suggestion is to go with `AsyncTask`.